# Translate function binding issue

Tags: java, sqlj

I am using SQLJ as the data set is quite large for the application. I am trying to incorporate a query into my SQLJ file, but at the time of binding it gives me an error. Please help me with an alternative to the same. I cannot drop the translate function as I have been told to do that only.

```
sql [myConn] cursor = { SELECT ORD_TEMPLT_GRP_ID,DSO_CD, ACCT_SUBTYPE_CD, 
GRP_DESC,LAST_CHANGED_BY_ID
FROM TEMPLATE_GRP
WHERE
TRANSLATE(ORD_TEMPLT_GRP_ID) = TRANSLATE(:templateGp)
WITH UR };
```

`cursor` over here is iterator and `templateGp` is the value which I am getting from an object.